# what is the difference between 'similarity to' and 'similarity with'?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I think of expressing that two things are similar by using the word of *similarity*. I know I can say 'A bears some similarity to B'. Can I also say 'A bears some similarity with B'? If both are correct, is there any difference?

Answer (score 9):

Both are found, but there is no obvious difference in meaning. *Similarity to* is the preferred construction in both American and British English. The Corpus of Contemporary American English has 332 records for *similarity to* and 52 for *similarity with*. The figures for the British National Corpus show a less pronounced preference, but, with corresponding figures of 105 and 34, it is still significant.

The Oxford English Dictionary supports this finding with 103 citations for *similarity to* and only 14 for *similarity with*.

Comment: I depend on Longman dictionary too much. I have been using it for nearly ten years. The question arises when I read it and it does not offer frequency of these collocations. Besides, I invented the sentence of 'A bears some similarity with B'. Longman dictionary provides other example of *similarity with*.

Comment: Having read Barrie's answer, I believe both expression are correct. 'A bears some similarity with B' may not sound authentic though. My lessons are, 1. not limited to one dictionary; 2. try to copy and use the word/collocation in the exact same as what is in dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

*Similarity to* is the more idiomatic in your example, but *similarity with* would be used if you were referring to shared similarities:

> **A** shares some similarities with **B**.

Comment: There's a distinct air of tautology about "sharing similarity", as borne out by the fact that [shares some similarity with](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22shares+some+similarity+with%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is ten times less common than [**has** some similarity with](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22has+some+similarity+with%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books.

Comment: These phrases are sensitive to pluralization and the use of *some*. Half as common: [shares some similarities with](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en&tab=pp#hl=en&q="shares+some+similarities+with"); Almost as common: [shares similarities with](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en&tab=pp#hl=en&q="shares+similarities+with")

Comment: Ah. I hadn't really registered the fact that you'd pluralised the noun as well as changed the verb. Yes, that same reduction in the preference for *to* occurs on Google Books, where [has similarities with](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22has+similarities+with%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) returns 53K hits against 90K for [has similarities to](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22has+similarities+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). But to my mind, if they're "shared", they're really *common characteristics*, not *similarities*.

Answer (score 0):

We usually say 'similar to' so the first sentence is the better one, but the second one could also be used.
It would probably depend on the context of the items/situations being compared.

Comment: I'd say that _similarity to_ is more common and idiomatic in American English. _Similarity with_ sounds strange to me. I don't recognize it as native-speaker English.

Comment: The wordings go 'similar to' or compared with' when using those.

Comment: The OP asked about "'A bears some similarity to B'. Can I also say 'A bears some similarity with B'?" He didn't ask about "'similar to' or 'compared with'", so I'm missing your point here.